# Mongoose model.save( ) is not working as expected

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this code and MongoDB is passing back an error after I attempt to save a new document:

```
   var data = {
       _id: '55d65cfde9cf73322361860b'  // _id is a string here
    };

   var model = new Model(data);

    model.save(function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            done(err);  //the error is captured here in my code
        }
        else{
            done(null, result);
        }
    });
```

and I get an error:

```
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: dev_local_db_smartconnect.jobs.$_id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('55d65cfde9cf73322361860b') }
```

however, I was under the impression that save would update the model/document if it exists (by using an implicit upsert=true option), and it would use the _id field to look for an existing document.

Does anyone know why this error would occur?

On the other hand, this works for me:

```
where data is the new data for the model, and _id is a string not an ObjectID, and Model is the mongoose class, not the instance.

 Model.update({_id:_id}, {$set: data}, {upsert:true} , function(err,result){
                if (err) {
                    done(err);
                }
                else if (result) {
                    done(null, result);
                }
                else {
                    done(new Error('grave error'));
                }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are creating a new local document Mongoose doesn't know it already exists on the server so it will try to save it as a new document. Mongo will then reject the document since an existing document with that ID already exists.

If you query for that document first and then save the returned document it would work as expected. Something like this:

```
Model.find({id: '55d65cfde9cf73322361860b'}, function (err, doc) {
  // update doc with something
  // ...

  doc.save(function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      done(err);  //the error is captured here in my code
    }
    else {
      done(null, result);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks Jason, this should work, I just would like to avoid two DB calls. I think there are a lot of people out there who don't see the need to retrieve the document from the DB, and then go update it, requiring a second DB call. In the second example I provided (which happens to work correctly), it should do everything with one DB call at no extra cost (TMK).

Comment: @AlexMills, to avoid that you can use the various `findAndModify` methods (e.g. `findAndUpdate`, `findOneAndUpdate`, `findByIdAndUpdate`, etc.). The main issue with using those is any schema validation for the document is skipped since it is modifying the document directly through Mongo. You can also use `Model.update()` but the same issue would apply.

Comment: yeah that's what I heard, I will just have to see if that becomes a problem. For puts and posts, the middleware and validation might be very useful, but for gets,deletes, probably can bypass it.